# Event object value returns undefined with certain international characters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

This is likely a bug with the event object.  Anyways, I'm running a trigger that detects edits on a Google Sheet.  The event object is called e.  If a particular cell in a certain column gets modified, my code looks at the value of the edit and then runs some logical operator and code.  For English characters, it works fine.  But, I just realized for certain Spanish characters, the object value (e.value) returns undefined.

There's not much to it.  I have some code below.  But, if the edited cell is standard English characters, I see that e.value returns the contents of the cell.

For example, I type `Yes` or `No` and `Logger.log(e.value)` shows Yes or No.  If I use `sí` or `ño`, `Logger.log(e.value)` shows `undefined`.

```
Logger.log(e.value)
```

Event object should record international character types.  But, it's returning `undefined`.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Try a different browser perhaps.

Comment: So far, I've tried latest Firefox and IE on Windows 10.  And Chrome 73 on Linux.  When I change cell to sí or ño, I still get undefined in Logger.log(e.value).  With IE, though, there's nothing.  It's just blank.  Why would the browser even matter, though?

Comment: Did you type/paste `sí` in a cell and press enter? Coz It got logged `si`  and `ño` in my logs.

Comment: Both.  Typed and pasted sí.  Still coming in as undefined.  In fact, I just tried again on my laptop at home vs work desktop, running latest Chrome on Windows, and it's still coming in as undefined.

Comment: I tried recreating your issue and it worked fine whenever I typed the words/symbols. However, it does return undefined whenever I pasted into the cell. I took the liberty of creating an [Issue Tracker issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/141085741) for this, you can check that link for updates.

Comment: Hi AMolina, I just verified on OS X with Spanish keyboard, and yes, it does capture the Spanish text in the event object.  Copy and paste still returns undefined.  On Windows, I'm getting undefined or nothing on various browsers and input keyboards.  Anyways, much thanks for this.  I hope it gets resolved.